# Is it sane to use Document based NoSQL for store big data tables

Tags: nosql

In Document based NoSQL to create tables (AFAIK) I need:

Create such many as many rows in table documents with same ID field (that will be table id) and each time need to set the columns (for each document).

Then you first search documents by id (table) and next search what you need in the selection.

Please correct if I understand it wrong... And is it sane? How could that be fast?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps. Only real way to tell is to setup some test cases and measure. My suspicion would be that how you are accessing the data in terms of pattern and usage matters most.

That said, thinking of document DBs in terms of tables is generally self-defeating. Think in terms of documents.

Comment: It's much easier for me to think about 100 nodes except of thinking about 100 documents with the same structure, and documents will be just realization, it's not hard to realize such "Table API" for documents, I really afraid usability and performance.

Answer (score 1):

Use the right tool to do the right thing. Documents databases should be used to store documents, not tables.  If the documents have the same columns a relational database is more appropriate to store it or maybe a graph database.

Answer (score 0):

What you describe (if I understand correctly what you describe) could be a performance nightmare in updating the said tables - if you store each "table" as a single document in a NoSQL system, and want to update a row in that "table", then you'd need to update the whole (potentially huge) document every time.

But if you need/want a strict structure, then why would you need to use NoSQL systems? For SQL type problems, SQL databases will be faster and better. For key-value type problems, key-value datasystems will be faster and better. For document storage type problems, document-based systems will be faster and better.